# How to plot data from msyql with google chart in wordpress

Tags: mysql, wordpress, charts

I have been struggling with adding

**`google chart`** with **my own `mysql` data** to my **`wordpress` page**.

When I use this code in a simple `html` form. It works just fine:
http://fiber.web.tuke.sk/mon/x.php

When I use in  in **`wordpress`** - **I never get that working**!!

Here is my code:

```
<?php
 $con = mysqli_connect('100.100.25.100','user','Pass123#','pi2w_station');

?>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
 google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
 google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

 function drawChart() {
 var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
 ['Date', 'Visits'],

<?php
 $query = "select  TimeStamp,temp_bmp180 from pi2w_attributes order by TimeStamp DESC LIMIT 100";

 $exec = mysqli_query($con,$query);
 while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($exec)){

 echo "['".$row['TimeStamp']."',".$row['temp_bmp180']."],";
 }
 ?>

 ]);

var options = {
 title: 'Date wise visits'
 };


var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('curve_chart'));
//var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById("columnchart"));
//<div id="columnchart" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
chart.draw(data, options);
 }

 </script>

<div id="curve_chart" style="width: 900px; height: 500px"></div>
```

Comment: What happens when you try to run it? Do you get any errors?

Comment: That is the thing, it does not throw any errors so it is hard to investigate. I spent like few days googling and trying to crack this problem. It is just a blank page with a page title. No errors in logs on Nginx web server.

Comment: Have you tested to make sure it renders anything?

Comment: I have no idea ho to test when executing javascript and a little bit of php.

when I tested php db connection: it worked. Any suggestions how to "debug"  ???

[{“Date”:”2015-11-03 09:17:09.430000″,”ROP”:”-47″},{“Date”:”2015-11-03 09:17:09.865000″,”ROP”:”-47″},{“Date”:”2015-11-03 09:17:10.170000″,”ROP”:”-24″},{“Date”:”2015-11-03 09:18:10.159000″,”ROP”:”-24″},{“Date”:”2015-11-03 09:19:09.894000″,”ROP”:”-24″}]

Comment: I would advice you to structure your code in some other way so you don't mix php and javascript the way you do now, but as a test it might be ok.
What do you get when you console.log the data object?
do you get any errors in the browsers javascript console?
Try to log everything that you are working on until you found out where things is not working. Divide your code into segments and test that segment to make sure it is working until you move onto the next one.

Comment: Here is the idea: I really need to plot data by using my own msyql connection and to be honest I do not quite understand the concept php and javascript working together. If you have any suggestion to write **php** mysql connection in javascript I am all for it. I also added : define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );  define( 'WP_DEBUG_LOG', true ); define( 'WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', true ); @ini_set( 'display_errors', 1 ); define( 'SCRIPT_DEBUG', true ); lines to wp-config.php however I do not see any ERRORS.